# Get filename of source JSP file (even if included)

Tags: debugging, jsp, filenames, jspinclude

I am trying to do some debugging of JSP files that include multiple levels of nested includes.

e.g.

```
foo.jsp
  <%@ include file="bar.jsp"%>

  bar.jsp
    <%@ include file="baz.jsp"%>

    baz.jsp
      <%@ include file="boz.jsp"%>
```

To help determine where a certain file is actually included I placed a simple line to output a javascript alert in various files so that I can catch it when a page is rendered.

e.g. (formatted over multiple rows for readability)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('Accessing File: <%=this.getName()%>' +
    '\n\nCompiled as: <%=pageContext.getPage().getClass().getName()%>' +
    '\n\nRequested by: <%=request.getRequestURI()%>');
</script>
```

Thus ideally what I want to see if I inject this into `baz.jsp` is:

> Accessing File: **baz.jsp**
>
> Compiled as: **_foo__jsp.java**
>
> Requested by: **foo.jsp**

However since the `<%@include%>` JSP directive is static - the content is included at translation time, thus everything becomes "**foo**".

I'd really, really like to not have to edit/hardcode a filename into each debug line I add.

Does anyone have a clever solution to obtain the "true" source filename of a JSP... if it is @included in another file?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but try using `<jsp:include>`

Comment: @Teja - unfortunately it doesn't make any difference... I think that is just the clean tag library "wrapper" to call @include

Comment: Ok, I will try if there are any other options. But there is a diff between how those both works, check herehttp://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=13517

Comment: `@include` is compiletime, `<jsp:include>` is runtime.

Answer (score 2):

`<jsp:include>` translates to `RequestDispatcher.include(..)` and is evaluated at request time, rather than statically. So try using it.